# SQL - Maestro en misma tabla con valor por defecto - Devolver los diferentes valores

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quisiera saber como (y si se puede) hacer en una misma consulta, siempre y cuando sea eficiente la siguiente consulta en SQL server:

Tengo una única tabla con los siguientes campos:
Id, CorporationId, Nombre, Valor.

En esta tabla existe unos "maestros" de tal forma que la Corporación siempre es nula, y se guarda de forma inalterada el Nombre y su valor.

Ahora bien, en ocasiones se insertaran filas con corporacionId pudiendo personalizar el valor para un nombre dado.

Por ejemplo:
- 1,null,Piso, 10
- 2,null,TErraza, 10
- 3, 150,Piso, 15

Lo que yo quiero es que si hago una busqueda por corporación, siendo corporación en este caso 150, se me devuelva la fila 2 y 3.
En caso de no pasar ninguna corporación que se me devuelva los valores por defecto, es decir, las filas 1 y 2.

¿Puede hacer esto en una sola consulta?

Gracias

EDITO:
he intentado esto:

(SELECT DISTINCT * FROM 
    t1 WHERE [CorporationId] is null

```
UNION

SELECT DISTINCT * FROM 
t1 WHERE [CorporationId] = 150)
```

Y mi idea ahora era quitar las filas que tiene coporation id a null, si existe una fila con corporation con valor y nombre duplicado

gracias

Comment: intentaste algo? si es asi, actualiza el post con el codigo!

Comment: lo intente, pero ahora mismo no tengo acceso al codigo. Es para ir viendo el tema, si es necesario, mañana añado lo que estuve probando.. gracias

Comment: No sé si entendí bien, pero con agregar la condición CorporationId = @parametro es mas que suficiente. Cuando sea null, devolverá los registros que tengan null. Cuando sea un valor distinto, únicamente devolverá los registros cuya corporación ID sea la misma.

Comment: @daicon es muy importante que siempre agregues lo que intentaste. Si no puede que alguien te conteste con algo que ya intentaste y no te sirvio.

Comment: He editado con lo que he intentado. gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes listar todos los valores por defecto unirlos con una `LEFT JOIN` con los valores de la corporación y, utilizando la función `ISNULL`, seleccionar el valor de la corporación en caso de existir y, si no es así, el valor por defecto.

La consulta podría quedarte:

```
SELECT ISNULL(C.Id, D.Id) Id, C.CorporationID, D.Nombre, ISNULL(C.Valor, D.Valor) Valor
FROM t1 D
LEFT JOIN t1 C ON C.Nombre = D.Nombre AND C.CorporationId=150
WHERE D.CorporationId IS NULL
```

Comment: joe, muchisimas gracias, perfecto! que maquina :-)
ahora tengo que convertir esta consulta a LinQ, a ver que tal jeje